# Count when event = 'birthday' and distinct user id

Tags: count, distinct

I can produce a query that looks at this separately but when I try and combine it I'm having an issue.

Original example query

```
Select account_name, count(distinct user_id)
from table 
where event like 'birthday'
group by account name
```

Any help greatly appreciated

When I try and combine this in a larger query that looks at multiple event types I'm having trouble getting it to count distinct users

What I'm trying

```
Select account_name, 
case when event_text = 'birthday' then count(distinct user_id) end 
case when event_text = 'wedding' then count(distinct user_id) end 
case when event_text = 'wedding' then count(distinct user_id) end 
from table
group by account_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is one table, you can try the following:

```
SELECT account_name, event, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY account_name, event;
```

At the end of the query you could add an optional ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY account_name
```

If you add this line of code you should put the semicolon from after the GROUP BY statement to the end behind the ORDER BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at your current code you are firstly comparing with the column `event` and after with `event_text`.

As you said the first query did work the second query should be
`case when event = 'birthday' then count(distinct user_id) end`  instead of `case when event_text = 'birthday' then count(distinct user_id) end`

also you should look into the `OR` operator : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp
which should definitely be used for comparing 1 value from the same column with multiple values